# How to sort alphanumeric list based on priority in groovy?

Tags: list, sorting, groovy

Below are 3 static lists

```
a_list = ["z1", "a2", "x4", "n7", "v10"]
b_list = ["l3","b10", "b1", "f5", "y23"]
c_list = ["l2", "c12", "d15", "n17", "c1"]
```

At any given payload I would get the below inputs with different input lists and priorities. Based on the priority, the output list has to be sorted to be on top

```
Input_list = ["f5", "y23","z1", "a2","l2", "c12"]
Priority = "c"
```

Expected Result:

```
Output_list = ["l2", "c12", "f5", "y23","z1", "a2"]
```

If the priority changes, then the sort order changes. How do I get this done in groovy?

Comment: What relevance do `[abc]_list` have to the problem (second degree sort?). Or is this just "keep original order unless the value starts with `Priority`"?

Comment: Is the requirement such that you want all elements in `Input_list` which begin with whatever the value of `Priority` is, should be in the output list before any items that do not being with whatever the value of `Priority` is?

Comment: The output list should just start with the values based on the Priority value. The order can be random, but if priority value is c all the items in c list should be on top

Comment: @cfrick the [abc]_list will be a list not starting with a/b/c... I had to create my own list without revealing the data

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd structure the config a little different.  Keep the
known priorities in a map, where the priority is the key and all the
values for that priority are in a set.

Then you can sort the payload by checking, if the payload item is in the
priority set (note that using just true/false to sort here might read
little odd, so feel free to switch over to returning `-1/1` or something
easier to grasp):

```
def priorties = [
    a: ["z1", "a2", "x4", "n7", "v10"].toSet(),
    b: ["l3","b10", "b1", "f5", "y23"].toSet(),
    c: ["l2", "c12", "d15", "n17", "c1"].toSet(),
]
def payload = ["f5", "y23","z1", "a2","l2", "c12"]
def priority = "c"

assert priorties.containsKey(priority)
assert payload.sort{ ! priorties[priority].contains(it) } == ["l2", "c12", "f5", "y23","z1", "a2",]
```

Comment: "This worked" - That is surprising.  You said "The output list should just start with the values based on the Priority value. The order can be random, but if priority value is c all the items in c list should be on top".  In the example shown the priority is `c` but none of the lists are being sorted to start with `c` items.   The sorted list shown is `["l2", "c12", "f5", "y23","z1", "a2",]`.

Answer (score 0):

> The order can be random, but if priority value is c all the items in c
> list should be on top

```
inputList = ["b10", "b1", "a1", "a2","c2", "c12"]
priority = "c"

inputList.sort {
  it.startsWith(priority) ? -1 : 1
}

// inputList will be [c2, c12, b10, b1, a1, a2]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your help!